# Django URL Regex Exact Match Only (Basic Regex)

Tags: python, regex, django

I am new to django and trying to build my first API.

The url structure is as follows but the problem is:

when the first part of the URL matches, it calls that one.

Ex. If I call `'welcome/example'` it matches with `welcome` and doesn't make it to the actual `welcome/example`...

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/', include('shopify_app.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('home.urls'), name='root_path'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^welcome/', views.welcome), 
    url(r'^welcome/example', views.create_example), #regex not working
]
```

Comment: your comment is wrong `#regex not working`,  Here only `regex` cause you to not have your desired output. Its just matches with your first welcome url i.e. `url start with string welcome`, thats it , it matches and reditects to view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

its better to use $ for exact match, so use this instead

```
url(r'^welcome/$', views.welcome), 
url(r'^welcome/example/$', views.create_example)
```

then go to `/welcome/` and `/welcome/example/`

Answer (score 0):

Yes its better to use $ for exact match as [answer given by @Exprator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47028682/3798217), if you don't want that,
then you can shuffle your url's order as

```
url(r'^welcome/example', views.create_example)
url(r'^welcome/', views.welcome)
```

Its a good practice to include main URL at the end after sub urls, then you don't fall in this kind of issues